# ChartJS works with Angular 5 while developing, but ng build fails

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular5

I am building an angular 5 app including a dynamic chart, that works perfectly.

Once I try to `ng build` it, I get

> ERROR in src/app/brand-details/brand-details.component.ts(87,18):
>   error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new'
>   keyword.

The offending part is :

```
this.chart = new Chart(this.htmlRef, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: chartValues,
      backgroundColor: COLORS,
      hoverBackgroundColor: []
    }],
    labels: chartLabels
  },
  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 20,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  }
});
```

and in particular `this.chart = new Chart(this.htmlRef,...`

Since someone requested, copying directly from `core.js` in chart.js library, here is the definition of Chart:

```
module.exports = function() {
  // Occupy the global variable of Chart, and create a simple base class
  var Chart = function(item, config) {
      this.construct(item, config);
      return this;
  };
  Chart.Chart = Chart;
  return Chart;
};
```

and I import it like this in my component:

```
import { Chart } from "../../../node_modules/chart.js"
```

Is there some parameter to use in order to prevent the build failure ?

Comment: What does `Chart` look like?

Comment: Hi @DanielWStrimpel I added the definition and the import in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the DefinatelyTyped definitions for chart.js included as dev dependencies?:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/chart.js
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7uuuf

Comment: I didn't have this, but even doing it, and then running `ng build` the result is still the same: `error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.`

Comment: Are you importing the Chart class from it? Can you expand you sample code to include the relevant imports stmts for Chartjs defs?

Comment: Hey @Chris White, I inserted in the question more details: I don't import anything via `<script>` but only with the `import` statement that I copied

Comment: I suspect your import needs to be amended. updated my answer to include a stackblitz sample that works without issue

Comment: Rewriting the imports following your indication I managed to get it working. I accepted your answer